# React with Foundation Slider

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, slider, zurb-foundation

Has anyone used foundation's slider component with React? I'm trying to capture and set the state based off the slider value, but I'm having serious issues. I'm looking for an approach that does not utilize jQuery.

When the input type is set to 'hidden' I can't seem to grab any data from the slider. When I change that to 'number', then an input box appears and I am able to grab data from that. The final design does not include an input box, so I need to maintain the 'hidden' attribute.

Can anyone seem to see a flaw in my code? At best, I get 'undefined' when trying to setState, but again, that's when I am showing an input box.

This is the code I have so far...

```
  export class _DailyCheck extends Component {
  state = {
    levels: {
      sleep: 0,
      energy: 0,
      stress: 0
    },
    show: true
  }

  _renderDaily () {
    const { levels: { sleep, energy, stress } } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='content'>
          <p className='headline-1 text-left'>
            How is your day
            going so far?
          </p>
          <div className='grid-x grid-padding-x'>
            <fieldset className='small-12 large-12 cell'>
              <label className='bold-body'>
                Sleep Quality
                <div
                  className='slider slider-margin'
                  data-slider
                  data-initial-start='3'
                  data-end='6'
                >
                  <span
                    className='slider-handle'
                    data-slider-handle
                    tabIndex='1'
                    aria-controls='sleep'
                  >
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className='slider-fill'
                    data-slider-fill
                  >
                  </span>
                  <input
                    type='range'
                    id='sleep'
                    value={sleep}
                    onClick={(e) => this._handleDailyChange(e) }
                  />
                </div>
              </label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  _handleDailyChange (event) {
    const levels = { ...this.state.levels }
    levels[event.target.name] = levels[event.target.value]
    this.setState({ levels })
  }
```